# Sync folders in sharepoint 2013 to Surface rt 2

Tags: 2013

I have a sharepoint 2013, on premise installation.

Everything are working, its published through forefront, using a bought certificate.

The problem I'm facing are when I'm using a Windows RT device (Surface 2)

Im able to do everything except one thing, that is to click the "sync" button inside sharepoint. It just pops up the question that I have not installed an app for this.

Even though, I have installed OneDrive Business.

When trying to open OneDrive Business I have to log on with a 365 account it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Store app ["OneDrive for Business"](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/d78bf57e-27fe-403e-b49b-701dedfdbf9e) is unfortunately for O365 only. From the description:

> OneDrive for Business, formerly SkyDrive Pro, is cloud storage for employees as part of Office 365 or SharePoint Online business subscriptions.

Looking at my Surface RT 1, I don't see a groove.exe running, which is the sync engine for synced folders on x86 office. Without that or a replacement, I'm not sure that it's possible to sync a folder to an RT device from an on-prem system.

You CAN use the "view in explorer" button, however. If this works (meaning WebDAV is supported on RT) I believe you should be able to map the SP library as a drive. This means that if your RT device is online, you may be able to meet your objectives. I know this probably isn't what you wanted to hear, but I think this is the current state of SP on prem and RT.

Comment: Hello. Thanks.

I can't even start to understand this. They want their RT platform to be the future. I can't really see how they can be serious about it when this is not working.

I know that they want to push their 365 products, but at the same time they should understand that not every company wants their data in the cloud

Anyway. Thank for your reply. WebDav by the way looks like its working, I'm able to open up the folder in explorer, but not able to open up documents. I will investigate further and update this thread for any future reference.